# Fix dependency issue gradle

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, unirest

I am trying to use the unirest library in my android application, in order to use mashape.com.  Unfortunately some unirest Apache dependencies conflict with some android Apache dependencies.  The issue can be resolved by following this blog post ([LINK](http://blog.mashape.com/using-unirest-java-for-your-android-projects/)), but only by using maven.  In this project I am using gradle and do not know how to resolve this issue.  What is the best way to resolve the issue and if I cannot what is another http client I can use instead unirest. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can give a try to retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit)